# Script for Kubernetes connectivity test

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a Jenkins script which test connectivity using this code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
    }
    
  stages{    
    stage('Ping Kubernetes') {
            steps {
                
                script{
                         sh '
                             curl -k  https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI......"
                         '
                    }
                }

            }                
        }    
    }
    
}
```

But I get error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 11: unexpected char: ''' @ line 11, column 29.
                            sh '
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a multiline string without using proper syntax (triple quotes)

As there's only one line, you can do this:

```bash
sh 'curl -k  https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI......"'
```

or this, if you want to use multilne strings:

```bash
sh '''
   curl -k  https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI......"
'''
```